# Random text on button click

Tags: android, button

I have around 150 different texts that I want to be shown in random order when I press a `Button`. A new one every time I press the `Button`. I have figured out this code:

```
   Random myRandom = new Random();
   TextView textblondin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textblondin);
   switch(myRandom.nextInt() %3) {
      case 0:
         textblondin.setText("Text 1");
         break;
      case 1:
         textblondin.setText("Text 2");
         break;
      case 2:
     textblondin.setText("Text 3");
     break;
      default:
     break;
   }
}
}
```

I can get it to linked to a `Button`. Anyone know how to do this?

```
public class Blondinskamt extends Activity {           <----X

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blondintext);
    View myRandom = findViewById(R.id.myRandom);
    myRandom.setOnClickListener(null);


    myRandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    TextView textblondin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textblondin);    <----X
    switch(myRandom.nextInt() %3) {
    case 0:
        textblondin.setText("Skämt");
        break;
    case 1:
        textblondin.setText("Roligt");
        break;
    case 2:
        textblondin.setText("kul kul kul kul");
        break;
      default:
```

}
}

I Still get errors where i put the "<----X" what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your onClickListener has no context from which to call `findViewById()`.  I would probably instead use the design pattern where your activity implements the click listener.  Read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html and search for "Easier click listeners".

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a Listener to your button.

```
textblondin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ... your code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Docs you can find how to execute code on a button click.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

store the all 150 strings in an Arraylist and display the text by randomly generated number.

samples;

```
ArrayList<String> arr_str = new ArrayList<String>();

arr_str.add(String Parameter) // add the all strings in arraylist by using the method.

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = 0;

within  the button onclick listener write the following code.
{
  randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(149);  // this will generate random number b/w 0 to 149.
textView.setText(arr_str.get(randomInt));  // you can get the n th number of string stored in the arraylist.
}
```

Comment: use Button myRandom =  findViewById(R.id.myRandom);
         myRandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });