# Next button for items xml file - android

Tags: android

I have a xml file with 500 texts. I have a button which take a sentace random and show it.
I want to add two more buttons for next and back. To take every sentace.
This is my code for rando button.

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
        Resources res = getResources();
        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.quote);
        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote);
                String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });

    }
```

What is the code for these buttons? Thank you

All code:

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Context context;
    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
    private AdView adView;
    int index = 0;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-7628432187347131/3277094808";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        context = this;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads_lin);
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("5B895A3CC0CA50D56506E300A4C8342B")
                .addTestDevice("D039292A1F434C999B21503D63D6FD88")

                .addTestDevice("TEST_EMULATOR").build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);

        Resources res = getResources();
        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.quote);
        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        Button btnPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPreview);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote);
                index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                String q = myString[index];
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String q = myString[index++];
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });

        btnPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String q = myString[index--];
                        tv.setText(q);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

No errors, but when I run the app, it stopped.

This is logcat:

```
09-20 17:24:53.341: E/dalvikvm(7651): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=568
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stiaica/com.example.stiaica.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at com.example.stiaica.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
09-20 17:24:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(7651):     ... 11 more
09-20 17:24:54.252: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7651): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I tried to change ActionBarActivity with Activity but more errors comes up.

Now is working, the buttons are working. But there is a problem, when I reached at last sentance and I press the next button the app stopped. THe same thing is for first sentance.

LOGCAT:

```
09-20 18:08:56.915: E/dalvikvm(20667): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
09-20 18:08:58.937: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:08:59.508: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:08:59.548: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:08:59.568: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:09:31.949: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:09:32.020: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:09:32.040: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:09:32.040: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:03.740: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:03.841: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:03.861: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:03.871: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:34.871: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:34.931: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:34.961: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:34.961: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20667): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=593; index=593
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at com.example.stiaica.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:73)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-20 18:10:40.226: E/AndroidRuntime(20667):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Always store the current index, and then put the index generator inside each button listener. For the previous button, you decrease the index by 1 and show the quote, for next button, increment by 1 and show, and for the random button, reuse the current logic (generate a random, store the index and show).

Comment: I am begginer and i don't know how to wrte the code for this :|

Comment: in your xml file your declaring your Button as ImageView that's your problem

Comment: thank you. now is working but there is another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the generated random in an index variable like this

> to move next increment that variable
>
> to move back decrement it

EDIT

Here is how to do it :

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        final int index = 0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
        Resources res = getResources();
        final myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.quote);
        final String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        Button btnPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String q = myString[index++];
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });

        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String q = myString[index--];
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });

       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote);
            index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
            String q = myString[index];
            tv.setText(q);
        }
    });

    }
    }}
```

Comment: Right now I am going to write the code. But you made me an ideea how must to be write.

Comment: I writed the code for next button, but an error comes up. "btnNext cannot be resolved"

Comment: you need to add 2 buttons next and previous in your layout file

Comment: I added. But now two errors comes up.

The final local variable index cannot be assigned.

Comment: Yes, at this lines index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
String q = myString[index++]; and String q = myString[index--]; this error comes up"The final local variable index cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing"

Comment: change final index to index (remove final) and declare index out of onCreate method

Comment: index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
String q = myString[index];
String q = myString[index++];
String q = myString[index--];

This error comes up: Cannot refer to a non-final variable index inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: Edited with implementation of Activity

Answer (score 0):

Put all the texts to an arraylist. Generate the texts randomly. And for next and back, get the position of the randomly generated text and increment position +1 for next and decrease position by 1 for back.

Check the comments in this post ,it will give you an idea on how to use arraylist for the texts. Hope it will help you. Cheers! :) [Random text on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437341/random-text-on-button-click)