# Change button text on click to random option

Tags: javascript, button, random

I have around 12 different word that I want to be shown in random order when the user clicks a button. A new one every time they press the Button. Is this possible to do with JS? I've tried the method shown here: [Random text on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437341/random-text-on-button-click)

```
   Random myRandom = new Random();
   TextView textblondin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textblondin);
   switch(myRandom.nextInt() %3) {
      case 0:
         textblondin.setText("Text 1");
         break;
      case 1:
         textblondin.setText("Text 2");
         break;
      case 2:
     textblondin.setText("Text 3");
     break;
      default:
     break;
   }
}
}
```

Would appreciate any help that points me in the right direction. I'm new to Javascript.

Comment: The code you posted from that link isn't JavaScript it's Android Java.

Comment: People actually confuse `Java` with `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your HTML:

```
<button onclick="randomWord()">
 Random Word
</button>
<div id="word">
  Click to display a random word
</div>
```

And this as your JS:

```
let randomWords = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];
let wordDiv = document.getElementById( 'word' );

function randomWord() {
    wordDiv.innerHTML = randomWords[ Math.floor(  Math.random() * randomWords.length ) ];
}
```

When you click the button it will find a random value from your array and set the div with ID "word" to this value. You can change the values in the `randomWords` array to whatever you like.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. I set it up like this:

`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
let randomWords = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];
let wordDiv = document.getElementById( 'word' );

function randomWord() {
    wordDiv.innerHTML = randomWords[ Math.floor(  Math.random() * randomWords.length ) ];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="randomWord()">
 Random Word
</button>
<div id="word">
  Click to display a random word
</div>

</body>
</html>
`

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to display the code properly in the comment.

Comment: Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/zs2j9pwg/